# Change the display order of the script "jQuery-File-Upload"

Tags: jquery, mysql, file-upload

I am using this [script](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

It works well, but I want to sort the results by placing the last image at the beginning of the list and not at the bottom. As the MySql ORDER BY....
Can anyone help me?
thanks

Comment: What do you mean As the MySql ORDER BY?

Comment: is just an example to understand what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news!  It's built right into the functionality as a configurable option.  Do this:

1. Open "jquery.fileupload-ui.js"
2. Search for "prependFiles:" (minus the quotes)
3. Change the value of "false" on this line to "true" (again, minus the quotes)

Your code will look like this when done:

```
// By default, files are appended to the files container.
// Set the following option to true, to prepend files instead:
prependFiles: true,
```

Answer (score 0):

The option you want is called: `prependFiles`

By default, files are appended to the files container.

Set this option to true, to prepend files instead.

Type: boolean

Default: false

( the above is from https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#prependfiles )

**You do not need to edit any core files such as jquery.fileupload-ui.js !!**

Instead just initialize your fileUpload component like this:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    prependFiles: true
});
```